# Android - How to add effect to show next video?

Tags: android, animation, video, scroll, android-video-player

I would like to add effect when I move to next video, some animation that the user can see that he is transferred to the next page(same page design just different video, but it would seem like feed of one page each time).

I use embedded YouTube video player, how can I reuse the same player when scroll to the next video.
Can I use ViewFlipper? or there is better way to implement it?
[Exampe of the flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RIaI.png)